# Trouble extracting individual JSON values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, reddit

I'm in the process of trying to scrape reddit (API-free) and I've run into a brick wall. On reddit, every page has a JSON representation that can be seen simply by appending `.json` to the end, e.g. `https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit.json`.

I installed NeatJS, and wrote a small chunk of code to clean the JSON up and print it:

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require 'open-uri'
require 'neatjson'

url = ("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit.json")

result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)

neatJS = JSON.neat_generate(result, wrap: 40, short: true, sorted: true, aligned: true, aroundColonN: 1)

puts neatJS
```

And it works fine:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(There's way more to that, it goes on for another few pages, the full JSON is here: http://pastebin.com/HDzFXqyU)</sub>

However, when I changed it to extract only the values I want:

```
url = ("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit.json")

result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)

neatJS = JSON.neat_generate(result, wrap: 40, short: true, sorted: true, aligned: true, aroundColonN: 1)

neatJS.each do |data|
  puts data["title"]
  puts data["url"]
  puts data["id"]
end
```

It gave me an error:

```
  002----extractallaskredditthreads.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0055f948da9ae8> (NoMethodError)
```

I've been trying different variations of the extractor for about two days and none of them have worked. I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious. If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong, that would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

It turns out I had the wrong variable name:

```
 neatSJ =/= neatJS
```

However, correcting this only changes the error I got:

```
 002----extractallaskredditthreads.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0055f948da9ae8> (NoMethodError)
```

And as I said, I have been attempting multiple ways of extracting the tags, which may have caused my typo.

Comment: `neatSJ` should be renamed into `neatJS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)

neatJS = JSON.neat_generate(result, wrap: 40, short: true, sorted: true, aligned: true, aroundColonN: 1)
```

...`result` is a Ruby Hash object, the result of parsing the JSON into a Ruby object with `JSON.parse`. Meanwhile, `neatJS` is a String, the result of calling `JSON.neat_generate` on the `result` Hash. It doesn't make sense to call `each` on a string. If you want to access the values inside the JSON structure, you want to use the `result` object, not the `neatJS` string:

```
children = result["data"]["children"]

children.each do |child|
  puts child["data"]["title"]
  puts child["data"]["url"]
  puts child["data"]["id"]
end
```

Comment: That didn't give me an error, but, it just printed 79 blank lines. Did I miss something?

Comment: I've edited my answer. There was additional level of nesting (`result["data"]["children"][idx]["data"]["title"]`, not `result["data"]["children"][idx]["title"]`) your code didn't account for.

Answer (score 0):

Is it  a typo?

```
neatJS = JSON.neat_generate
[...]
neatSJ.each do |data|
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake, sorry.  However, after I corrected that, it just gave me another error:          002----extractallaskredditthreads.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0055f948da9ae8> (NoMethodError)