# Ruby JSON extractor failing, possibly due to overly large JSON

Tags: ruby, json, reddit

I was in the process of creating a script to extract all of the comments from a Reddit Thread as a JSON:

```
 require "rubygems"
 require "json"
 require "net/http"
 require "uri"
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'neatjson'

 #The URL.
 url = ("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/46n0zc.json")

 #Sets up the JSON reader.
 result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
 children = result["data"]["children"]

 #Prints the jsons.
 children.each do |child|
   puts "Author:       " + child["data"]["author"]
   puts "Body:         " + child["data"]["body"]
   puts "ID:           " + child["data"]["id"]
   puts "Upvotes:      " + child["data"]["ups"].to_s
   puts ""
 end
```

And for some reason it gives me an error. However, the error is not in the actual JSON printer, but in the reader:

```
   005----extractallredditpostcomments.rb:17:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
           from 005----extractallredditpostcomments.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

For some reason,

```
children = result["data"]["children"]
```

Isn't working, which is strange because it worked fine [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515733/trouble-extracting-individual-json-values-in-ruby/35515971)

What I'm wondering is: Could this be causes by the size of the JSON? If you actually go to the link (https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/46n0zc.json) you can see that the file is huge. I'm having so much trouble finding the tags I need due to the sheer size of the page, it took me hours and I'm still not sure I have the correct ones, that could be causing the error as well. I'm not sure what's failing here.

Oh, and one last thing: I tried simplifying the program by removing the printer:

```
 #Sets up the JSON reader.
 result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
 children = result["data"]["children"]

 puts children

 #Prints the jsons.
 #children.each do |child|
 #  puts "Author:       " + child["data"]["author"]
 #  puts "Body:         " + child["data"]["body"]
 #  puts "ID:           " + child["data"]["id"]
 #  puts "Upvotes:      " + child["data"]["ups"].to_s
 #  puts ""
 #end
```

And it still fails:

```
005----extractallredditpostcomments.rb:13:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
        from 005----extractallredditpostcomments.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with size. [Yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35515733/179125) you were accessing a different URL that returned an entirely different JSON structure. That URL returned a JSON object with a `data` property, whose value was an object with a `children` property, ergo `result["data"]["children"]`. The URL in your code above returns a JSON array, not an object, and you'll have to access the data accordingly.

Comment: P.S. The error message ("no implicit conversion of String into Integer") tells you the same thing. You're trying to use a string key (`result["data"]`) where it's expecting an integer (e.g. `result[0]`).

Comment: @Jordan, I'm not too familar with JSON, but I noticed both you Kadar referred to a "JSON array" as opposed to "array". Is that just a shorthand way of referring to an array that was obtained from a JSON object?

Comment: @CarySwoveland JSON is a data serialization format that defines *objects*, an unordered key-value structure denoted by square brackets analogous to Ruby hashes or YAML mappings, and *arrays*, an ordered list denoted by curly braces analogous to Ruby arrays or YAML sequences. When I said "JSON object" and "JSON array" I was referring to the yet-to-be-deserialized data structures described by the JSON files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the returned JSON value shows that it is a JSON **array** of two JSON objects and not a JSON object. It looks somewhat like this:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "after": null,
            "before": null,
            "children": [
                {
                    "data": {
                        "approved_by": null,
                        "archived": false,
      ...
      },
      "kind": "Listing"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "after": null,
            "before": null,
            "children": [
                {
                    "data": {
                        "approved_by": null,
                        "archived": false,
                        "author": "finkledinkle7",
                        "author_flair_css_class": null,
                        "author_flair_text": null,
                        "banned_by": null,
                        "body": "My mother was really sick in 2008.  I was turning 25 with a younger brother and sister.\n\nLost both of my grandparents on mom's side to cancer a few years prior.  Mom had to watch as her parents slowly passed away.  It destroyed her not having her mother around as t ...
   }
]
```

This means that the line `children = result["data"]["children"]` in your program won't work because it is treating result as a JSON object. It looks like you should do `children = result[1]["data"]["children"]`.

Comment: Huh. I wondered why I wasn't getting the correct results. Thanks a lot, I was really stuck there for a while.

Comment: It gives me the first 200 responses, and then an error, but that's OK, I'm using a different method for those.